# Need help on a getting the count with grouping

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table with the following columns

---

Table 1

```
Site  Det  FailFlag  Comments  ModifiedDate  ModifiedBy    
ABT   A01     F      Dfasdf    10/11/2011    Anna
ABT   A01     F      dsfsdf    15/12/2012    Mand
ABT   A01            Rds       30/03/2011    Tim
ABT   A01            GHDs      02/12/2012    Andy
ABT   A02     F      dfd       09/05/2012    Anna
ABT   A02            sdada     11/02/2013    Kathy
ABT   A02            Dfg       15/05/2011    Rob
TRG   A01            sdasd     16/04/2010    Richard
TRG   K05            jksdh     23/04/2012    Mark
KLD   KO5     F      sd        18/05/2013    Jim
KLD   KO5            dsfsd     10/03/2012    James
KLD   KO5            sdsd      12/05/2011    Luther
```

I need to get the following as output :

```
Site  Det  Count  CountOfFailures
ABT   A01     4      2
ABT   A02     3      1
TRG   A01     1      0
TRG   K05     1      0
KLD   KO5     3      1
```

I know that I can group by Site and Det and get the count but unable to get the count of the number of failures

```
Select Site,Det, Count(*) AS [Count] from Table1  
group by Site,Det  order by Count
```

Need help on the same.

Comment: you need to add case in where or group by clause, case FailFlag = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS FailFlagNum and than count it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
  Select site,det,
  FlagCount = sum(case when FailFlag='F' then 1 else 0 ENd) 
  from yourTable
  group by Site,Det
  order by Site
```

Output

```
  +------+-----+-----------+
  | site | det | FlagCount |
  +------+-----+-----------+
  | ABT  | A01 |         2 |
  | ABT  | A02 |         1 |
  | KLD  | KO5 |         1 |
  | TRG  | A01 |         0 |
  | TRG  | K05 |         0 |
  +------+-----+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen. This was exactly what Ive been looking for. This works good.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a case statement.

```
SELECT Site, Det, COUNT(*) AS [Count], SUM(CASE WHEN FailFlag  = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfFailures 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Site, Det
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
Select  [Site],
        [Det], 
        Count(*) AS [Count],
        SUM(CASE WHEN FailFlag = 'F' THEn 1 ELSE 0 END) [CountFailed]
from    Table1  
group by    [Site],
            [Det]  
order by    [Count]
```